# Strange results from addition of two array constructors

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am trying the following code, which simply adds two array constructors to get a one-dimensional array. However, depending on whether `one` is used in these expressions (outside implied DO loop), I get incorrect results with gfortran-5.3 for (1), (3), and (6). On the other hand, ifort-14.0 and Sun fortran 8.7 give correct results for all  cases. Strangely, if I try a similar but more complicated expression, even Sun fortran starts to behave strangely (i.e., it gets frozen during compilation...) So I am wondering whether I am using some wrong or dangerous syntax in these expressions. Any idea...? (BTW, if I leave only one constructor between the two, they always work as expected.)

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer :: k
    integer, dimension(2), parameter :: zero = [0,0], one = [1,1]
    integer, parameter :: N = 1

    print *, [  one,   ( zero, k=1,N) ] + [ ( zero, k=1,N),  one   ]  !! (1)
    print *, [ [1, 1], ( zero, k=1,N) ] + [ ( zero, k=1,N), [1, 1] ]  !! (2)
    print *, [  one,   ([0, 0],k=1,N) ] + [ ([0, 0],k=1,N),  one   ]  !! (3)
    print *, [ [1, 1], ([0, 0],k=1,N) ] + [ ([0, 0],k=1,N), [1, 1] ]  !! (4)
    print *, [  1, 1,  ( 0, 0, k=1,N) ] + [ ( 0, 0, k=1,N),  1, 1  ]  !! (5)
    print *, [  one,   ( 0, 0, k=1,N) ] + [ ( 0, 0, k=1,N),  one   ]  !! (6)

    print *, [ (one, k=1,1), (zero, k=1,N) ] + [ (zero, k=1,N), (one, k=1,1) ] !! (7)
endprogram
```

Results with ifort14.0 and Sun Fortran 8.7:

```
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
```

Results with gfortran-5.3:

```
       1           1           0           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           0           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           0           1
       1           1           1           1
```

Comment: Those look fine to me.

Comment: @francescalus OK, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are as expected when using the **associate** construct

```
    program main

        use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: &
            compiler_version, &
            compiler_options

        implicit none
        integer :: k
        !integer, dimension(2), parameter :: zero = [0,0], one = [1,1]
        integer, parameter :: N = 1

        associate( zero => [0,0], one => [1,1] )
            print *, [  one,   ( zero, k=1,N) ] + [ ( zero, k=1,N),  one   ]  !! (1)
            print *, [ [1, 1], ( zero, k=1,N) ] + [ ( zero, k=1,N), [1, 1] ]  !! (2)
            print *, [  one,   ([0, 0],k=1,N) ] + [ ([0, 0],k=1,N),  one   ]  !! (3)
            print *, [ [1, 1], ([0, 0],k=1,N) ] + [ ([0, 0],k=1,N), [1, 1] ]  !! (4)
            print *, [  1, 1,  ( 0, 0, k=1,N) ] + [ ( 0, 0, k=1,N),  1, 1  ]  !! (5)
            print *, [  one,   ( 0, 0, k=1,N) ] + [ ( 0, 0, k=1,N),  one   ]  !! (6)
            print *, [ (one, k=1,1), (zero, k=1,N) ] + [ (zero, k=1,N), (one, k=1,1) ] !! (7)
        end associate

        print *, 'This result was compiled by ', &
            compiler_version(), ' using the options ', &
            compiler_options()

    end program
```

Using GNU Fortran (Debian 5.3.1-14) 5.3.1 20160409 I get

```
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1
       1           1           1           1

       This result was compiled by GCC version 5.3.1 20160409 using the options -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -O3 -Wall -std=f2008ts
```

Comment: Removing the **parameter** attribute also yields the expected results.

Comment: I see... I have tried removing the "parameter", and it does give the expected result also on my computer (CentOS + gfort4.8 or 5). So the culprit seems the parameter attribute...